# Exception code c0000005 app crash

Tags: c

Good morning to everybody.
I'm working on a CUDA project in which I need to manipulate some 2D arrays that are dynamically created by using the `malloc` function.

I report here the entire code of the file on which I'm currently working on:
http://pastebin.com/mcFdH4kQ

When I try to execute the code after generating the .exe file, I encounter an ACCESS_VIOLATION error that causes app crash. Probably, the main problem deals with the function called `setArrayItemAtXY`thanks to which I'd to save a given integer value within the matrix I passed as parameter, in a pre-determined (x,y) position.

Is there any problem regarding the syntax? Which may be the issue?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a problem, but not with the syntax (at least not directly) but with the [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The dereference operator `*` have lower precedence than the array index operator `[]`. That means an expression such as `*array[x * cols + y]` is parsed as `*(array[x * cols + y])`. And that is not correct.

The simple solution is to change the function to *not* take a pointer to a pointer, as this is actually not used inside the `setArrayItemAtXY` function. Just have it take a normal pointer, and use plain `array[x * cols + y]` (without dereference).

So change the declarations to:

```
void setArrayItemAtXY(int * array, int cols, int x, int y, int value);
//                        ^
//                        |
// Note: Single pointer here
```

You of course need to modify all the calls to the function as well.

It should also be noted that this should have caused the compiler to complain, in that you treat a value as a pointer. If you don't get compiler warnings from that, then you need to enable more warnings.

Comment: Operator precedence is part of the syntax though.